# Grails 3 - findAllBy with join

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1

I have a domain class:

```
class Owner {
    Integer ownerType
    Prop propertyToJoinSometimes

    static constraints = {
        propertyToJoinSometimes nullable: true
    }
}
```

I usually don't want to load propertyToJoinSometimes when loading Owner, but I sometimes load many Owner objects at once using findAllBy, and a join could save a large number of calls to the database. Is there a way to do something like:

```
Owner.findAllByOwnerType(2, [propertyToJoinSometimes: [fetch: 'join']])
```

Comment: do you use everything from propertyToJoinSometimes or are you then using bits from owner and bits from propertyToJoinSometimes to make up your presentation ? Reason I ask - you can refer to an earlier answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363404/grails-3-return-list-in-query-result-from-hql-query/38393443#38393443

Comment: haha haha it was you who had asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for (not using the dynamic finder `findAllBy`) but it produces the results you are after.  The grails documentation for createCriteria/withCriteria does not mention it but there is a `fetchMode` method within the [HibernateCriteriaBuilder](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.5/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html).

```
import org.hibernate.FetchMode   

Owner.withCriteria {
    eq('ownerType', 2)
    fetchMode('propertyToJoinSometimes', FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an option using dynamic finder:

```
Owner.findAllByOwnerType(2, [fetch: ['propertyToJoinSometimes': 'eager']])
```